# How to access section property inside a delegate of DelegateModel

Tags: qt, model, delegates, qml

Consider following code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQml.Models 2.2

Window {
    width: 200
    height: 100
    visible: true
    DelegateModel {
        id: visualModel
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement {
                name: "Apple"
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "Orange"
            }
        }
        delegate: Rectangle {
            height: 25
            width: 100
            Text {
                text: "Name: " + name + " Current section: <insert current section here>"  ; // How to get section here
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: visualModel
        section.property: "name"
        section.criteria: ViewSection.FullString
        section.delegate: Text {
            text: section
        }
    }
}
```

here I needed to access attached section property from ListView inside visualModel's delegate, but I can't seem to get it, I tried different combinations like directly accessing it or through model's property but nothing seems to work, any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#a-note-about-accessing-attached-properties-and-signal-handlers

basically you have to use this syntax -> `<delegate root item>.ListView.section`
so above working code will look like this

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQml.Models 2.2

Window {
    width: 200
    height: 100
    visible: true
    DelegateModel {
        id: visualModel
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement {
                name: "Apple"
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "Orange"
            }
        }
        delegate: Rectangle {
            id: root
            height: 25
            width: 100
            Text {
                text: "Name: " + name + " Current section: " + root.ListView.section  ; 
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: visualModel
        section.property: "name"
        section.criteria: ViewSection.FullString
        section.delegate: Text {
            text: section
        }
    }
}
```